# friend-selector : get user ID of the selected friend

Tags: facebook, user-interface, components

I need to create a graphical interface that displays the current user's friends and when you click one of these users need to receive in return the ID of the user so they can perform some processing based on business rule of my application. I wonder if there is any component that offers this functionality (click on a friend and get the id of my friend).

When I say "component" I mean the UI's such as friend-selector: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/friend-selector/
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **NO** official [plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/) to do this. You need to:

1. Build your own (won't be hard at all)
2. Try [googling](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=jquery%20facebook%20friends%20selector&btnG=Search) for existing ones